# Where to download OS X Mavericks out from Mac App Store?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

Can I download OS X Mavericks not from App Store? Considering that my internet speed is very slow, so I prefer to download the OS from my other laptop, rather than leaving the download from Mac App Store in my MacBook.

Comment: The only other alternative is if Apple decide to sell it preloaded on a USB stick, which is what I believe they did for a limited time with OS X Lion (if i'm not mistaken).

Comment: If there is another Mac somewhere with faster internet, and you can use your Apple ID on it to download Mavericks, then that same copy could be installed on the Mac you want.  (Haven't tried this myself yet, but it was OK in Mountain Lion.)

Comment: I ended up downloaded Mavericks myself, it only took 14 hours :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to obtain Mavericks legally is through the App Store, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Visit this link.
There are some OS X versions, original from app store.
http://mhs-notes.blogspot.com/2016/08/direct-download-macos.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please refrain to link-only answers. We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Links can change over time and then we lose the question-answer context. See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review -

Answer (score 0):

You can't from the appstore but you can from torrent sites, remember you only can use it for a hackingtosh build because apple doesn't allow you to down grade from software. they kinda do but it depends what the first software was on your mac computer, you can make a fresh installation on it with the fist software and you can set the back-up back. and then only upgrade to the latest version of os x.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has started to deliver the full macOS installers outside the App Store. Here is a script that checks the current downloads and finds High Sierra and Mojave installers.

- [Is there a script I can use to download the Mojave installer without being signed in to the App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/337450/5472)

I haven’t picked apart the data it downloads and reads to see if it’s just not seeing the older OS or if those older verisons of OS (Mavericks for example) just don’t ship outside the Mac App Store.