# Is there a script I can use to download the Mojave installer without being signed in to the App Store?

Tags: macos, command-line, mac-appstore, script

Is there a way to script and download the Mojave installer without signing in to the App Store?

Something other than opening or clicking a url that points to the installer on the Mac App Store would be ideal.

Comment: you will still have to provide your credentials.

Comment: You'll be amazed by a very nice python script that I've come across that does this unexpected thing @Buscar웃 - hang tight...

Comment: how about this https://github.com/maxschlapfer/MacAdminHelpers/tree/master/AppStoreExtract

Comment: I'd not seen that shell script @Buscar웃 - it seems to repackage an app you already downloaded, but it's coming from the same community of Macintosh administrators that have collaborated to make the munki tools like the python script I asked this question so I could share an answer here. Thanks - I hadn't seen that +1

Answer (score 18):

There is a very well documented open source script that reads the software update catalogs and parses them for the major macOS installer components, prompts you which build and version to download and will then commence to download each portion to your filesystem and then build an installer application or image based on the options you choose.

- https://github.com/munki/macadmin-scripts

The python script named [installinstallmacos.py](https://github.com/munki/macadmin-scripts/blob/main/installinstallmacos.py) has this description:

> A tool to download the parts for an Install macOS app from Apple's
> softwareupdate servers and install a functioning Install macOS app onto an
> empty disk image

This tool is updated for macOS 10.15 Catalina.

Comment: I have to do `sudo python ./installinstallmacos.py` right? But I get `ImportError: No module named xattr` It would be very nice if you could give a working example. edit: turns out I have to install `pip install xattr` ok now it says `could not find a default catalog url for this os version` I'm on El capitan.

Comment: bmike Hello! Have you had success with this script downloading old mac os versions? Like Mavericks or Yosemite or Lion etc.?

Comment: In the past @Shayan yes - lately we just run caching server and use the new store links - much better now that Apple makes it easy to find the older versions and install them