# Cannot pause downloading mojave from launchpad

Tags: mac-appstore, launchpad, mojave

Today I started to download macOS Mojave from app store and it appeared in launchpad as usual. When I tried to pause the download by clicking on the downloading icon, it won't pause. I can only delete the download by long press on it. The same thing happened previously when I tried to download High Sierra 10.13.6.

Another way I tried to pause the download from app store but I can only pause the apps but not the OS download.
[image]

Is there a way by which I can pause the download?

Comment: did you right click on it ?

Comment: Yes. I tried both one by one....left click and right click.

Comment: I am able to Pause it in App Store.

Answer (score 1):

This topic is quite old, but I found out that connecting my VPN will abort the download. All already downloaded data is then lost.

Maybe this is helpful for others with the same problem.

BR
Cryptos

Answer (score -1):

What it does works is in App Store, you can Pause it there.

[image: pause]

Since I just downloaded Mojave, I can not verify your claim.

However, it is possible that App Store has disabled the Pause function in times with high demand, to allow for high bandwidth.

Comment: Please see the updated question.

Comment: see updated answer

Comment: you might want to read this https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/337453/46541

Comment: I just downloaded macOS Mojave and I can verify that there was no way to pause the download of macOS Mojave in the App Store. Also, you said "However, it is possible that App Store has disabled the Pause function in times with high demand, to allow for high bandwidth.", which frankly makes no sense whatsoever! How does disabling the Pause function in times of high demand allow for greater bandwidth? Logic would dictate it one could pause a download that it would then increase the bandwidth available to others!

Comment: @user3439894 appreciate you feedback but your logic is faulty, think of it this way, allowing people to pause, for how long, min,hr, days, will keep the server busy maintaining the situation more then just downloading. On top of all that you are occupying a "slot" thus not allowing others to use it. In today's world it takes 20 minutes to download the file. Pausing it will just make that time on the server much longer. You are probably not old enough to remember when Apple Servers crashed during such times of high download demands.

Comment: When a download is paused, the connection to the server is not held open indefinitely and after a relatively short period of time the connection is completely dropped for other users to have access. Those times are adjustable base on load and the pauses really do not slow down the ability of other connections to be established. The servers are capable of handling the status of all the connections with little to no effort. In a given 24 hour period of time the impact the pauses have are negligible and allow the bandwidth being used prior to be pause back into the pool.

Comment: Also, not everyone has the speed available to download, e.g., the Install macOS Mojave.app released the other day and 6,033,610,515 bytes (6.03 GB on disk), on my system, in 20 minutes. As to "You are probably not old enough to remember when Apple Servers crashed during such times of high download demands." I do not know how you could assume that as I was around in the punch card days long before Apple was anything other then a piece of fruit!

Comment: @user3439894 now I am waiting in anticipation to hear from you why there is no Pause on Mojave but there is on everything else. You might disagree with my theory, but have not offered anything worth while.