# Where can I get macOS Catalina Beta version?

Tags: macos, catalina

I have a MacBook Pro which came with macOS Mojave pre-installed. I have heard that macOS Catalina is releasing this fall.

I want to use the beta version of it. Where can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Public beta for macOS Catalina is now released by Apple. The same is available to download from [Apple Beta Software Program](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/) website.

You can find handy guides for installing public betas here:

- [Guide for Public Betas](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/guide)

To download the macOS Catalina installer, select macOS tab on top of the page and under **Get Started** section click on [enroll your Mac](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/redemption#macos) link.

Comment: While enrolling I get this "To continue your enrollment, complete your purchase now." and asking me to pay $99

Comment: Is it free? You mentioned its free.

Comment: @Roshan Indeed. My bad, while it is possible to register as an Apple Developer for free, you need be on a paid membership to download macOS Catalina beta. Let me update the answer.

Comment: Can I get atleast the public beta for free when it comes?

Comment: @Roshan Yes. Public beta is meant for general public and the public beta software will be available here: https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/ I'll also mention it in the answer.

Comment: @Roshan As luck would have it for you, the public betas just got released! I have updated the answer.

Comment: You actually don't need to strike out text you deleted. Everybody interested in the changes can access the edit history, and it's easier to read without  the strike outs.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not on the Apple Developer Program and you want to test the beta OS, you'll have to wait until the public beta is available.

For macOS and iOS beta versions, the public beta dates have not been announced yet.  You can go to [the Apple Beta Signup](https://beta.apple.com/sp/betaprogram/).  The production release date of Catalina hasn't been announced.

[image]

Comment: The site is down. I'd wager that public beta is about to be released any minute now.

Comment: @NimeshNeema That's so funny, I was just on the site getting the screenshot!  Everything was working a few minutes ago.  It seems too early for a public beta.  I'm used to at least 3 dev betas before the first public one.  We'll see...

Comment: After all these years I still wonder why Apple isn't able to switch to new version of a page (hierarchy) more or less instantly.

Comment: Let me entertain you with an interesting tidbit. Some pieces of Apple website backend are so archaic they they have to take the server down to update them. Hence, server going down is a good indication of some activity happening :D

Comment: @nohillside My guess is they don't have enough resources to dedicate and there's no pressing need to get it done. Any ain't it fun for us folks to feel the anticipation :D

Comment: @fsb The dog's out! Told ya :P

Comment: @NimeshNeema Great timing!  The site is getting hammered right now.  It's really slow.  And now all the "I'm on the Mac beta, my computer won't boot, and I don't have a backup" questions will start in earnest.

Comment: @fsb My experience during the last few years has been that any beta/public OS release by Apple is made on Monday around 10:30 AM Pacific Time. This is time most engineers check into work. In my understanding, that's the time when the engineers are back after the weekend, afresh, and prepared to quickly handle any unforeseen, zero day issues.

Comment: Just leaving this here... https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337450/is-there-a-script-i-can-use-to-download-the-mojave-installer-without-being-signe