# macOS Catalina beta could not be verified

Tags: macos, beta-seed-program, beta, catalina

I'm trying to install the latest beta on my MacBook and always get the message at the end:

> macOS Catalina beta could not be verified

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: If you list the steps how you came to get the installer - whether you are using a profile or download it might spark someone's memory. Also, consider that many people will decline to speak since all the Catalina programs I've seen have pretty strict non disclosure agreements that cover discussions of it outside the program forums until release.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["macOS Catalina" could not be verified](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372328/macos-catalina-could-not-be-verified)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just retied and it worked out of the box.
Don't know what the error was, I did not change nothing.

Comment: Sometimes a download error is just a download error. Glad it’s sorted - be sure to check your answer as solving this in a day or so. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Are you scripting your download:

- [Is there a script I can use to download the Mojave installer without being signed in to the App Store?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/337450/is-there-a-script-i-can-use-to-download-the-mojave-installer-without-being-signe)

That can help isolate things in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

change Date&Time to “Apple Americas / U.S. .....”