# "macOS Catalina" could not be verified

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, catalina

I'm trying to upgrade my MBP 2018 to Catalina, but everytime I finished download it, the error pop up as below:
[image: "macOS Catalina" could not be verified]

I downloaded it almost 10 times, but no success

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365476/macos-catalina-beta-could-not-be-verified

Comment: @ankii I've done several things, including restart, update date & time, shutdown, etc, none of them work. Anyway it's from main update, not beta.

Comment: It is actually a question on apple discussion forums too.Also, I don't know how long will it take to appear on combo updates page. https://support.apple.com/downloads/macos It was worth a shot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally I got MBP upgraded to catalina! This is how I succeed upgrade my MBP after many times redownload and reinstall failure:

1. Open System Preferences
2. Choose Sharing
3. Check on 'Content Caching'
4. In preference Cache, choose 'All Content'
5. First trial it gives me same error ("macOS Catalina" could not be verified).
6. Second Trial, because the failed download file 'cached' it took me about 10-15 seconds to redownload (get from the cache)
7. It's successfully verified and macOS Catalina installing!

Maybe it's only happen to my device (MPB 2018 with touchbar), but give it a shot!

[image: Mac OS Catalina]

Comment: Not working when upgrading to `Monterey`