# "Unable to verify MacOS" when upgrading to Monterey

Tags: macos, install, upgrade, verify, monterey

Shows error popup `Unable to verify macOS` when I tried several times to upgrade macOS from `BigSur` to `Monterey`.
Also tried [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/372545/424730) but not working.

- Error Screenshot :
  [image: error dialog]
- Log Screenshot :
  [image: Logs]

Installer log :

- Error logs :
  [Open github gist](https://gist.github.com/Shah-Aayush/3ddeb534d0cbf5bf2429da80c6a67a40)
- All logs :
  [Open github gist](https://gist.github.com/Shah-Aayush/4b1102bbe8f9fce2207d15a95f7ab827)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got same error here, i think that this line matters:
`Oct 26 12:26:09 Aayushs-MacBook-Pro osinstallersetupd[965]: Personalization summary: 20G165 -> 21A559 (Customer), global = 0, variant = multiple, client = osinstallersetupd, user auth = 0, tdm = 0, prod fused = 1, model = j132ap, bridge = 18.16.14759.0.1,0, session = 1377012F-B0D8-4061-8C5A-23057FB93DCE: Error Domain=OSPErrorDomain Code=201 "An error occurred during personalization." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=An error occurred during personalization., NSUnderlyingError=0x7fe18798ab70 {Error Domain=AuthInstallErrorDomain Code=14 "(null)"}}` 
I think it's due to you're in a VPN network or sth that makes apple think that you're in a different country? I solved it by turning off my VPN agent.

Comment: My vpn was not turned on. But I guess my university internet blocked this update server site. So when I connected to my personal wifi It worked!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it on my [Intel MacBook Pro 2019](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/boot-modes-sec7703b1423/1/web/1). ([Mac M1 info here](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/boot-modes-sec10869885b/1/web/1)) The first step was probably unnecessary, as it found no problems.

1. Restart and use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> at boot to enter recoveryOS and run Disk First Aid on the main drive.
2. Restart and use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to boot into the Internet recoveryOS and install the latest macOS
3. Get brunch/supper/play some games while your Mac grinds away for an hour or two. It will restart a few times.
4. Hello Monterey!