# Getting "unable to verify macOS" when upgrading to Catalina

Tags: mac, mojave, upgrade, catalina

I am using version **10.14.6** of macOS currently. When I try to upgrade to macOS Catalina using software update panel, I get this error every time.

```
"unable to verify macos"
```

MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018)

**NOTE** the installation process starts and after 4-5 minutes this error comes up.

Comment: For beta: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/365476/macos-catalina-beta-could-not-be-verified?noredirect=1&lq=1 and exact duplicate with no answers: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372328/macos-catalina-could-not-be-verified?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @ankii dont mind but the questions are not EXACT duplicate ..

Comment: Yeah. the scenarios are different.

Comment: In case you have not yet solved the issue, [edit] to explain how those answers don't help you and flag for moderator attention for reopening request. See this article for understanding this :) https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions